# How to get selected files actual path instead of fake or temporary file path?

Tags: javascript, php, file, browser

In order to get file path i am using following function in javascript, but as i want actual file whole path instead of fakepath or temporary path. this code does not meet my requirement.

I have use following code in order to display path

```
$(function()
{
    $('#fileUpload').on('change',function ()
    {
        var filePath = $(this).val();
        console.log(filePath);
    });
});
```

but this displays following as output:

```
C:\fakepath\test.xls
```

as far as i know, because of security concern browser dont allow direct path read of file. but how can i solve this by changing browser setting in order to get actul path of selected file. as i am developing system that will run on local system i don't have to look into security concern but i want result.

Comment: The browsers protect the users privacy, with javascript you will not be able to get the original filepath

Comment: i have tried the suggested link already but in mozilla it gives me fake path. i want actual path so i can process some operation on that directory

Comment: Try this
var file = $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0].name;

Comment: You can not get the actual path, the browser prevents you from doing that

Comment: any alternative way to get the actual path.